# Custom tab bar images overlapping when bolded(Accessibility)

Tags: ios, xcode

This is easier explained through a pictures:

Exhibit 1 Regular, accessibility bold off:

[image]

Exhibit 2 Bold on (settings accessibility option):

[image]

exhibit 3, bold on but system icon for the first tab bar view, instead of custom:

[image]

I've played around with the settings and I still can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same question in the future.

It appeared I was using outlined icons which is not allowed, I solved this through changing my icons to solid.

as outlined in apples docs: 
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/